# How run code when app loaded from home page/Local notification?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

When I run the app via xcode, then go to the homescreen and reload the app through either a local notification or pressing the icon, the code in my viewDiDLoad is not run, only when the app is killed and totally reloaded.

I basically want the app to be fresh every single time the app is loaded up. How do I get the effect of that initial view did load without killing the app every time? Is there a certain viewDiD______ that loads when the app is pulled from being minimized?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a notification and open the app that way, you're informed via delegate methods in your `AppDelegate` - here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:) to the documentation that discusses the various ways you can get info and respond to it.

You're asking a separate question though, because `viewDidLoad` is called only once in the lifecycle of each of your controllers. There isn't a way to cause them to simply disappear and it reloaded.

One solution you might do is set a global variable when your app is relaunched (which can be detected in `applicationDidBecomeActive`), and then in `viewWillAppear` of your controller, check for that variable and take action accordingly to look fresh (and then make that variable false).

One word of caution though - it may not be a good user experience if someone quickly switches out of your app (or receives a notification, even), and it resets to fresh.

Comment: I dunno if I'm doing something silly here, but I messed around with it and it didn't work, but I definitely see the train of thought.

Does viewWillAppear definitely run each time the app loads up? Cause when i even do a print in my viewwillappear I only get something the first time, where as the print in the didbecomeactive happens every time. And ofc it only checks for the variable set in the delegate once as well.

Comment: Ah I think you're correct on that point. May need to use a notification to alert the controller in that case